# AngularJS ou JSF qual escolher?

Tags: angularjs, jsf

Pessoal o time de desenvolvimento da empresa onde trabalho esta decidindo qual tecnologia usar para um projeto web que esta por vir. Foi analisado alguns pontos e ficamos em duvida entre essas duas tecnologias que é Angular e JSF.

Sei que a produtividade com Angular é ótima me oferece ótimos recursos e uma alta performance.

Porem como é Javascript fiquei um pouco inseguro com relação a segurança a proteção do meu código, mesmo separando e colocando as regras de negocio na parte do backend ainda sim não estou seguro em relação a segurança. Sou apenas um estagiário e não possuo tanto conhecimento nessa parte.

Com o JSF eu vou ter essas vantagens? A Tecnologia é ultrapassada? Eu sei que depende muito do tipo de aplicação para que eu vou utilizar sera que compensa, terei mais segurança do que com Angular? Existem formas de manter meu codigo mais seguro com o Angular? Essas são as principais duvidas, estou pesquisando mais a fundo esses pontos porem gostaria de opiniões de pessoas com mais experiencia.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Acho que tua pergunta se encaixa em **Principalmente baseada em opiniões**, afinal só você (e sua equipe) sabe o que é melhor para o projeto. Vocês que irão desenvolver, não nós. Talvez você possa [edit] sua pergunta e especificá-la, falar um pouco sobre o projeto. Caso contrário, eu tenho quase certeza que ela será fechada.

Comment: Olha, segundo o que li esses dias atrás JSF esta caindo em desuso sendo substituida por outra maneira de fazer que agora não lembro o nome, consideraria levar em consideração o AngularJS. Respondo apesar da pergunta podendo ser principalmente baseada em opniões.

Comment: Como isso vai de opinião, eu usaria AngularJS. Por que? JSF está perdendo muito mercado, além de que trabalhar com JSF e Web designer não é uma tarefa fácil por causa dos componentes do JSF. Atualmente o JSF se encontra na versão 2.2, se não estou enganado, e agora está pra lançar o MVC 1.0 http://www.infoq.com/br/news/2015/07/jsf23-mvc10 . Além disse, reaproveitar componentes no JSF não é um trabalho tão fácil, é difícil. Sem falar em varias chamadas ajax bugadas. 

AnguarJS te da várias possíblidades, a comunidade esta a 1000 com isso, sem falar na facilidade em aprender e desenvolver.

Comment: Eu trabalho com JSF, se seu projeto for simples creio que não vai ter problemas, mas se tiver janelas complexas recomendo AngularJS, como já dito nos comentários anteriores JSF tem muitas limitações.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian sugiro que poste uma resposta com este comentário - mesmo que não especificamente a respeito de implementação, é válida pelo ponto de vista de suporte às tecnologias.

Comment: Nossa exatamente isso que queria ler, estava aqui procurando sobre reaproveitamento de componentes no JSF é como você @Paulo Gustavo falou é bem mais complicado, e também pelo fato de estar caindo em desuso, fico grato pela ajuda de vocês.

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian Fiquei curioso para saber onde você leu que o JSF está caindo em desuso, porque não encontro nada a esse respeito. Será que não leu que era o JSP que estava ficando obsoleto em favor do JSF?

Comment: Li nesse livro amigo: http://novatec.com.br/livros/javaparaweb/